# TypeError: Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty pd.DataFrame `df` with `col1` set as `category`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": []})
df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype("category")
```

I have also a pd.Series with one value set as a category

```
s = pd.Series(["MP1"])
s = s.astype("category")
```

When I try the following

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].combine_first(s)
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories
```

**What I've tried**
Adding the category from the pd.Series into my empty DataFrame

```
df["col1"].cat.add_categories(s.cat.categories.to_list())
```

But it didn't seems to work, I got the same error and when I output the category it looks like it didn't add anything

```
[in]-> df["col1"].cat.categories

[out]-> Float64Index([], dtype='float64')
```

Comment: Why do you have to set the empty column categorial?

Comment: Usually it had data but in some case the dataframe is empty and I got this situation

Answer (score 0):

I think `.add_categories` returns a new dataframe, without modifying the original one, so you would need to assign the result to a new dataframe.

I ran `df_new = df["col1"].cat.add_categories(s.cat.categories.to_list())`, and `df_new.dtypes` told me that it contains `CategoricalDtype(categories=['MP1'], ordered=False)`.